# Sequences, subsequences, sub-subsequences and convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Take the metric space (X,d). Let $\{{x_n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in X. If every subsequence has a sub-subsequence and every sub-subsequence converge to the same $x^*$ prove that the original sequence must also converge to $x^*$.

This is what I did:

define $\{{x_{k(n)}}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as a subsequence of $\{{x_n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.
Assume that $\{{x_{k(n)}}\} \nrightarrow x^*$ then $\exists\epsilon>0$ $\forall N$ $N\in\mathbb{N}$ $\exists n>N$ such that $d(x_{k(n)},x^*)>\epsilon$ if this is true than there will be a sub-subsequence that does not converge to $x^*$ but this contradicts the statement therefore the subsequence $x_{k(n)}\rightarrow x^*$.
Now suppose $x_n \nrightarrow x^*$ this means $d(x_n,x^*)> \epsilon$ so this means we can biuld a subsequence that does not converge to $x^*$, however this contradicts the fact that the subsequence $x_{k(n)} \rightarrow x^*$. Therefore the sequence $x_n \rightarrow x^*$.

Is this proof right or am I assuming too much?

Comment: "every subsequence has a sub-subsequence" is always true...

Comment: So what am I missing here?

Comment: Well, since you can choose your sub-subsequence to be simply your subsequence, the claimed proposition is immediately equivalent to "If every subsequence converges to the same $x^*$ then the original sequence converges to $x^*$." Which is a true statement, by the same proof that you've given (with extraneous bits omitted). But I'm guessing you've butchered the actual statement of the problem somehow.

Comment: I did because in the original statement was not clear whether the sub-subsequences shared the same limit with the subsequence or not. So I went to the professor and asked him, he told me that the statement just says that the sub-subsequences all share the same limit $x^*$ but nothing is said about the subsequence.

Comment: But the subsequence itself is a subsubsequence (as @Dustan explained) hence the hypothesis does say something about the subsequence.

Comment: I understand that but when I showed him the proof that the sequence converges to the same limit of the subsequence he said I was assuming too much.